# When I pass a list to another method, it returns NoneType. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a `main()` method that will call another method that reads the individual records within a .txt file; this is the `loadFile()` method. I've tested that the `loadFile()` method works and that the list it returns is ListType. However, when I call `loadFile()` within `main()` and try to act upon the list generated, I get an error like `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Can someone help me ensure that the list I'm passing from one method to the next remains ListType?

```
def loadFile(fileName):
    openFile = open(fileName, 'r')
    records = openFile.readlines()
    recordList = []
    for item in records:
        recordList.append(item.rstrip('\n'))
    print(recordList)
    openFile.close()

def main():
    nameFile = 'names.txt'
    names = loadFile(nameFile)
    print(names[12])

main()
```

Comment: You forgot to `return recordList` at the end of `loadFile`.

Comment: You didn't return anything. `print()` is not a method to pass data between functions, that's a way to write data *to your terminal screen*. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: MartijnPieters, thank you. That's my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing, you should `return` the value from your function.

```
def loadFile(fileName):
    openFile = open(fileName, 'r')
    records = openFile.readlines()
    recordList = []
    for item in records:
        recordList.append(item.rstrip('\n'))
    openFile.close()
    return recordList

def main():
    nameFile = 'names.txt'
    names = loadFile(nameFile)
    print(names[12])

main()
```

If you don't explicitly return anything, functions in Python will always return `None`.